# Zend/Gdata - getDocumentListFeed

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, google-docs

Hello guys,

I use the Google API Zend and I need to list all the documents of certain accounts. The problem is that when calling the method **getDocumentListFeed** if the writely Service Account google account is disabled it throws me an exception (code 401). And I do not want that. I'd like to try before if the service is running, but I can not find a way to give me the information ?
    
**Docs.php**
    
const AUTH_SERVICE_NAME = 'writely';
    
**My Classe**

```
protected function GetAllDocumetsOneCollab
                   (   $UidToWork
                     , $PasswordGet
                   ) {
  try {
    $service             = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME ;
    $client              =
       Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient
                   (   $UidToWork.
                       "@".$this -> DomainToUsed
                     , $PasswordGet
                     , $service
                   ) ;
  } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $e) {
    throw new Exception
                   (   "[".__LINE__."] ".__FILE__.
                       $this -> CrLn.
                       $this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.
                       $UidToWork." // ".$PasswordGet.
                       $this -> CrLn.
                       $this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.
                       $this -> DepileErrorCatch ($e)
                   ) ;
    return null ;
  }

  try {
    $docs                = new Zend_Gdata_Docs ($client);
  } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $e) {
    throw new Exception
                   (   "[".__LINE__."] ".__FILE__.
                       $this -> CrLn.
                       $this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.
                       $this -> DepileErrorCatch ($e)
                   ) ;
    return null ;
  }
  $AllDocument           = array () ;
  try {
    $feed                = $docs -> getDocumentListFeed () ;
    foreach ($feed -> entries as $entry) {
      $link              = $entry -> getLink () ;
      $Title             = $entry -> getTitle () ;
      $AllDocument    [count ($AllDocument)] =
          array (   'title' => utf8_decode ("".$Title)
                ) ;
    }
  } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e) {
    throw new Exception
                   (   "[".__LINE__."] ".__FILE__.
                       $this -> CrLn.
                       $this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.
                       $this -> DepileErrorCatch ($e)
                   ) ;
    return null ;
  }
  return $AllDocument ;
}
```

I would like to test just before if the service is enabled like that :

```
    $IsEnable            = $docs -> ServiceEnable () ;
    if ($IsEnable)
      $feed              = $docs -> getDocumentListFeed () ;
    else
      $feed              = array () ;
```

The Exception message : 

*Expected response code 200, got 401
Service  disabled by Google Apps admin.
Error 401*

I do not know if one API method or property can give me the information?

Thank you all and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I did it like that even if I do not like this solution

```
  $service               = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME ;
  $AllDocument           = array () ;
  try {
    $feed                = $docs -> getDocumentListFeed () ;
    foreach ($feed -> entries as $entry) {
      $link              = $entry -> getLink () ;
      $Title             = $entry -> getTitle () ;
      $AllDocument    [count ($AllDocument)] =
          array (   'title' => utf8_decode ("".$Title)
                ) ;
    }
  } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e) {
    $Response            =  $e -> getResponse() ;
    $MsgError            = $Response -> getMessage() ;
    $MsgErrorAccept      = "Service <".$service."> disabled by" ;
    if (!strstr($MsgError, $MsgErrorAccept)) {
      throw new Exception
                     (   "[".__LINE__."] ".__FILE__.
                         $this -> CrLn.
                         $this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.$this -> Space.
                         $this -> DepileErrorCatch ($e)
                     ) ;
      return null ;
    }
  }
  return $AllDocument ;
```